# Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110) for bluetooth device

Tags: embedded, bluetooth

While connecting hciattach its connecting everytime ,but hciconfig hci0 up is giving result as
"Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)"

```
# rfkill list
1: phy0: wlan
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: hci1: bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
4: hci2: bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
# hciconfig -a

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
        TX bytes:12 acl:0 sco:0 commands:3 errors:0
        Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
        Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1
        Link policy:
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```